# Unable to click enter text for a webelement whose id and value changes every next time it is chosen

Tags: java, selenium

I have a student text box which accepts a value and search the student in the list below.
This is how the console looks for the element for the first time

```
input type="text" class="studSearch" id="esearch0" name="esearch[0]" 
value="Select student to enable"
```

When i enter all the values after that and click on "add another student" button, the next time student text box looks like below

```
input type="text" class="studSearch" id="esearch1" name="esearch[1]" value="Select student to enable"
```

I am storing the elements in a database and fetching it in the code. I am declaring the initial element in the database as `Name = esearch[0]`
I want a way to write a prog dynamically so that i declare the web element once but use it when i am adding 3 students also one after the other?

Comment: Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
WebDriverWait waitElmt = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element = waitElmt.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[contains(@name,'esearch')]")));
element.click();
element.sendKeys("somethingText");
```